# foreach object script alternatives for faster execution

Tags: powershell

I have the below code that does what I need however it is slow am wondering if there is any faster alternatives that could do the same.

```
$array2= ('italy', 'mexico', 'australia')

$pattern = '(?:total residents\s: )\W(\d+)\W'

$array = $array2 | ForEach-Object {
    $array3 = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Select-string -Pattern $_ -SimpleMatch -Context 9, 0 | ForEach-Object { 
        $_.Context.PreContext
        $_.Line
        $_.Context.PostContext
    }
    $array3 | Select-String -Pattern $pattern | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
}
```

$array2 could have elements up to 10 this is just an example with 3.

file contains data in following format dots represent other information I don't need this is just how part of it looks so country line is 9 lines below total residents.

total residents : (15899630)
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
country : italy

============================================================

Output from above script:

15899630
2442110
1500000

Comment: what if you store Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse in a variable instead of calling it for every pattern?  In order you can improve this you need to tell us a bit more about the bottleneck. For example: How many $array[2]? how many files do you get?

Comment: array2 usually has 5 to 14 elements i take each elements as patterns to get a string that is related to each pattern by number of lines hence context , i only match elements from one file path which is $path

Comment: you are reading the same files million times - that is the slow part of your code. read the files only ones and iterate on the pattern instead

Comment: @iRon - I edited the post it is more clear now and you can test the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be useful to know the regex pattern and the input format of your data, but based on the sample script provided, I'd suggest:

- Only reading each file once
- Replacing your second `Select-String` invocation with `-match/$matches`

Something like:

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -File){
    foreach($item in $array2){
        $file |Select-String -Pattern $item -SimpleMatch -Context 9, 0 |ForEach-Object { 
            $_.Context.PreContext
            $_.Line
        } |ForEach-Object {
            if($_ -match $pattern){
                $Matches[1]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is 3x faster thank you very much , would please explain a bit why my code was so slow and this is very fast  I am new to powershell so that would help me alot thank you again.

Comment: @3N16M4 - the pipeline is inherently slower than a standard loop like `foreach`. plus, `ForEach-Object` is very, VERY flexible ... and that means it is somewhat slow. so the `foreach` loop can often be as much as a _full order of magnitude faster_ than using the pipeline and FE-O.

Comment: What @Lee_Dailey + we're allowing file system caching to do it's job by repeatedly accessing the same files rather than "rotating" through them all

Answer (score 1):

Since `Select-String` takes an array of patterns, I don't see a reason to pipe an array like that.

This may not be functional, but I think it's going in the right direction:

Note: Combining some of Mathias R. Jessen's work below:

```
$Result =
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -File |
Select-String -Pattern $Array2 -SimpleMatch -Context 9, 0 |
ForEach-Object{
    $_.Context.PreContext
    $_.Line
    } |
ForEach-Object{
    If( $_ -match $pattern ) { $_.Matches[1] }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are not enough details in your question to create a proper answer (and test it) but **caching** the matches my help depending on the contents of your files, the arrays and the `$Pattern`:

This generally how you might approach this (*but could not test*):

```
$Cache = @{}
Function GetMatch($Item) {
    If (!$Cache.ContainsKey($Item)) {
        $Text = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Select-string -Pattern $Item -SimpleMatch -Context 9, 0 | ForEach-Object { 
            $_.Context.PreContext
            $_.Line
            $_.Context.PostContext
        }
        $Cache[$Item] = $Text | Select-String -Pattern $pattern | ForEach-Object { $Item.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
    }
    $Cache[$Item]
}

$array = $array2 | ForEach-Object {
    $array3 = GetMatch $_
}
```

<sub>(Note that I purely based it on your example in your question and didn't even try accommodate the **valid** answers from the others which I recommend you to try combine.)</sub>

Comment: you're not passing `$_` (`$array2`) to `GetMatches`

Comment: @Mathias, thanks for the comment. You are right, the current item (`$_`) should be the key in this (I have updated the example)